# Add Video button is not clickable on Magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, product, product-video

I am trying to add video into my store via admin product edit page.
I have already added a youtube api key but when i click on Add Video button than nothing happens.

[image]

When i check the error log than its showing

```
main.CRITICAL: The element 'gallery' already has a child with alias 'content' {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): The element 'gallery' already has a child with alias 'content' at /var/www/vhosts/demo/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:611)"} []
```

Thanks for your answer in advance.